# Generate months between StartDate and EndDate (SQL Server 2016)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a Customer table and I need to generate the months between active date and inactive date.

Here's the raw data:

[image: Here's the raw data:]

Here's the output I am hoping for:

[image: Here's the output I am hoping for:]

Thank you

Comment: Most people here want sample data and the expected result as formatted text, not as images (or links to images.)

Comment: Have a calendar table with all possible months. (Or a cte). Outer join.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
    with yyyymm as (
      select customerid,
             datefromparts(year(activedate), month(activedate), 1) as dte,
             datefromparts(year(inactivedate), month(inactivedate), 1) as inactivemonth
      from Customer
      union all
      select customerid,
             dateadd(month, 1, dte),
             inactivemonth
      from yyyymm
      where dte < inactivemonth
     )
select CustomerId, year(dte) * 100 + month(dte)
from yyyymm
order by dte
```

This produces the results as the first date of the month.  If you want the year/month value to be a string or number, you can format it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes Gordon's script(I am sorry I am new member as well, I can't add comments). I believe this is what you want.

```
WITH Cus AS 
(
    select CustomerId   
            ,DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(ActiveDate),MONTH(ActiveDate), 1) as ActiveDate
            ,DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(InactiveDate),MONTH(InactiveDate), 1) as InactiveDate
    FROM Customer
) 
SELECT * 
FROM Cus C
INNER JOIN CustomerMonths CM ON C.CustomerId = CM.CustomerId
WHERE DATEFROMPARTS(LEFT(CM.MONTHS,4),RIGHT(CM.MONTHS,2),1) BETWEEN C.ActiveDate AND C.InactiveDate
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I don't have customermonths table. That's the output I was hoping for. I need to generate the months between Active and Inactive dates.

Comment: So, you can check Gordon's answer.